# No qmlviewer installed

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml, qt5

I've installed Qt SDK 5.0.0 beta 2 and Qt Creator 2.6.0. It detects the package but gives a warning that "No qmlviewer installed". I've looked for it and it is in the SDK bin folder. What can I do? I use ubuntu 12.04 and I've added the SDK binaries to the PATH. I can view the QML files through the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Usually we add SDK binaries to the PATH environment variable. Please include information you may find relevant like the operating system you use.

Comment: @thejartender I've added the details you asked for.

Comment: Is this an uncommon problem? If so, how can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a solution but maybe it will be helpful.

I can see this warning too, but I think it is not a big problem. I have started to move my existing Quick1 code to new Qt version and I have not seen Qt5 Kit in the drop down list. But when I have created new Quick2 application I found it. And everything seems to work without QMLviewer.

Btw, I found forum [post](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19787) about Qt5 and qmlveiwer. Guy says that it was very difficult to support viewer in the actual state because API of declarative modules are changing very quickly. So they have dropped qmlviewer from Qt5.